# background gradient is not working on mobile browser

Tags: css, background, linear-gradients

This is very strange that gradient does work in a desktop browser but the same version of the mobile browser does not display gradient.

When I run the following code, it works on my desktop but not on mobile,

```
.div1 {
    height:100vh;
    background:linear-gradient(180deg, #5bd495 20%,  #7fe5a2 20% 100%);
}
```

I tried it in chrome and safari. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: your gradient value is not valid try this `linear-gradient(180deg, #5bd495 20%,  #7fe5a2  100%)`

Comment: Well, I want my gradient to stop at 20% and switch to next color, hence this syntax. Don't forget this gradient works on a desktop browser, only mobile is creating the issue.

Comment: then remove `100%` at last....not required

Comment: no need 180deg as it's the defaul value ... you can simplify like this `background:linear-gradient(#5bd495 20%,  #7fe5a2 0);`

Comment: Wow! Like for real? How does one thing works fine on desktop and not on mobile? Removing 100%,  displays my gradient perfectly. Thanks for your help.

Comment: How about if I have multiple gradients? is this the right syntax? background:linear-gradient(90deg, #E4F8EB  12.5%,#92DDB4 12.5% 12.7%, #F8FFF9 12.7%);